# How prove this equality $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n_{k}}C_{n}^{r}M^{N-n_{k}+r}x^{n_{k}-r}\le(1+1)^N(M+x)^N$

Tags: inequality

prove that
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n_{k}}C_{n}^{r}M^{N-n_{k}+r}x^{n_{k}-r}\le(1+1)^N(M+x)^N$$

and $x\in R,x>0, n_{k},N \in N^{+},N-n_{k}+r>0,n_{k}-r>0$

where
$C_{n}^{m}=\dfrac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you can prove that (thanks to binomial coefficients)

$\sum_{r=0}^{n_{k}}C_{n_k}^{r}M^{N-n_{k}+r}x^{n_{k}-r} = M^{N-n_k} (M+x)^{n_k}$.

Assume $M>0$.

So now we need to prove that $\left(\frac{M}{M+x}\right)^{N-n_k}\le 2^N$, which is obvious.